# how to stop switching of tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs

I my application am using four tabs . Each tab contains an acticity. So one of tab contains downloa Activity where i use to download some content from web. I have a case where i need stop switching of tabs , when download process is going on.

i.e; In download tab , when download is going on , it should'nt switch tab.

Can any one gimme an idea about it.
Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override onTouch() of tabHost

```
int numberOfTabs = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
for (int t = 0; t < numberOfTabs; t++) 
{
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {   
            return true;
    });
}
```